# Hindi Font not coming properly in some client computers

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, fonts, flex4.5

We have developed Adobe air application that has option for Hindi and English. For translation we used microsoft office Hindi Pack and used on-screen keyboard to write in hindi. We have used Arial font in application.

In some of the client computers when language is changed to Hindi we see boxes in place of the words. The client computer is having Arial font available.

We are ready to embed the correct TTF file in our application but we are not sure which font file is being used by successful machines as we did not install any special font. Please help.

== Update===

Found there is an option to embed the font of the system application is compiled on. For that I used following code but it is not working:

```
[Embed(systemFont="arial", fontName="myArial",
                    mimeType="application/x-font", advancedAntiAliasing="true")]
        protected var fontClass:Class;
```

and then in css file added

```
global
{
     font-family: "myArial";
}
```

But I am getting errors:

```
    Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
exception `during transcoding: Cannot embed local font 'arial' as CFF. The CSS @font-face 'local()' syntax is not supported. Please specify a path directly to a font file using the 'url()' syntax. For [Embed] syntax the 'systemFont' attribute is not supported. Please specify a path directly to a font file using the 'source'` attribute.   HondaLMS.mxml   /HondaLMS/src   line 81 Flex Problem
```

and

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
unable to build font 'myArial'  HondaLMS.mxml   /HondaLMS/src   line 81 Flex Problem
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the systemFont name is "Arial", not "arial" (they are case sensitive).

If that does not work, try to embed it in css:

```
@font-face 
{
   src: local("Arial");
   fontFamily: "myArial";
   unicodeRange: U+0020-00FF; // change the range for your desired english and hindi characters, numbers and punctuation, otherwise you would embed ALL characters including cyrillic, chinese, arabic and whatnot and it would become  huge
}

global
{
   font-family: "myArial";
}
```

If it won't work with the font name reference, just copy the Arial font into your project directory and embed it with a relative path:

```
@font-face 
{
   src: url("../assets/Arial.ttf");
   fontFamily: "myArial";
   unicodeRange: U+0020-00FF; // change the range for your desired english and hindi characters, numbers and punctuation, otherwise you would embed ALL characters including cyrillic, chinese, arabic and whatnot and it would become  huge
}
```